# python interpolation between dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, interpolation

I want to do interpolation between 2 columns from 2 dataframes

dataframe1

```
+-------+----------+--------------+---------------+-------+-----------+
| index |   time   | displacement | normal_stress | speed | amplitude |
+-------+----------+--------------+---------------+-------+-----------+
|  1227 | 1412.341 |     0.232728 |     94.508177 |   0.1 |         2 |
|  1228 | 1413.389 |     0.234591 |     98.358851 |   0.1 |         2 |
|  1229 | 1414.450 |     0.235065 |    104.554040 |   0.1 |         2 |
+-------+----------+--------------+---------------+-------+-----------+
```

dataframe2

```
+-------+----------+--------------+---------------+-------+-----------+
| index |   time   | displacement | normal_stress | speed | amplitude |
+-------+----------+--------------+---------------+-------+-----------+
|  1227 | 1412.341 |     0.232728 |     94.508177 |   0.1 |     10000 |
|  1228 | 1413.389 |     0.234591 |     98.358851 |   0.1 |     10000 |
|  1229 | 1414.450 |     0.235065 |    104.554040 |   0.1 |     10000 |
+-------+----------+--------------+---------------+-------+-----------+
```

from dataframe1 to dataframe2 I have manually changed all values in the column `amplitude` to 10000. Now I want corresponding values in column `time` in dataframe2 which are increasing with time.

expected output

```
+-------+----------+--------------+---------------+-------+-----------+
| index |   time   | displacement | normal_stress | speed | amplitude |
+-------+----------+--------------+---------------+-------+-----------+
|  1227 | 76566.341 |     0.232728 |     94.508177 |   0.1 |       10000 |
|  1228 | 76567.389 |     0.234591 |     98.358851 |   0.1 |         10000 |
|  1229 | 76569.450 |     0.235065 |    104.554040 |   0.1 |         10000 |
+-------+----------+--------------+---------------+-------+-----------+
```

I have tried this code but values in column `time` for dataframe2 are not linearly increasing

```
time_1 = dataframe1['time'] 
amp1 = dataframe1['amplitude'] 
amp2 = dataframe2['amplitude'] 
dataframe2['time'] = np.interp(time_1, amp1, time_2)
```

Comment: expected output?

Comment: hi, could you please provide details on the function you need to use for interpolation and needed output like @rafaelc mentioned?

Comment: expected output would be values in column `time` in dataframe2 as somewhere between 100000 because it is linearly increasing with column `amp`

Comment: so if I understand correctly, you need to linearly correlate amplitude as function of time? as in `amplitude = some_constant * time` ?

Comment: I put amplitude value myself manually. It should remain constant in all rows. so equation should be rather `amplitude*some_constant=time`